# Is it possible to make home screen widget from webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, rss, android-widget, feed

How to make home screen widget from webview?

Or do you know how do I can use rss feed in my app? Any good tutorial or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make home screen widget from webview?

That is not possible, sorry.

> Or do you know how do I can use rss feed in my app?

Parse it yourself or use a third-party JAR like [android-rss](https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss), and display it however you like (e.g., `ListView`).

> Any good tutorial or something?

There are many RSS reader tutorials, [on the Web](http://goo.gl/aH9Iv), in [books](http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials), etc.